# Mysterious problem with Extern

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scope, extern

In my project I've **AuxState.h** where I define

```
extern NSString *kStrAgentStateLogin;
extern NSString *kStrAgentStateAvailable;
extern NSString *kStrAgentStateLogOff;
extern NSString *kStrAgentStateLunch;
extern NSString *kStrUnavailable_IDLE;
```

In **AuxState.m** I have

```
NSString *kStrAgentStateLogin; 
NSString *kStrAgentStateAvailable;
NSString *kStrAgentStateLunch;
NSString *kStrAgentStateLogOff;
NSString *kStrUnavailable_IDLE;
```

In my **Appdelegate.m** I've imported **AuxState.h** and have defined the following method which sets the **extern** variables

```
-(void) languageSetupForAuxStates
{

/* 1st Part */

kStrAgentStateLogin     =  @"Log In";
kStrAgentStateAvailable =  @"Available";
kStrAgentStateLunch     =  @"Lunch";
kStrAgentStateLogOff = @"Log Off";
kStrUnavailable_IDLE =  @"Unavailable/IDLE";

if([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"ja"]){

    kStrAgentStateLogin=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAuxStatesDictFile ofType:@"plist"]] allKeysForObject:kStrAgentStateLogin] objectAtIndex:0];
    kStrAgentStateAvailable=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAuxStatesDictFile ofType:@"plist"]] allKeysForObject:kStrAgentStateAvailable] objectAtIndex:0];


kStrAgentStateLunch=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAuxStatesDictFile ofType:@"plist"]] allKeysForObject:kStrAgentStateLunch] objectAtIndex:0];

kStrUnavailable_IDLE=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAuxStatesDictFile ofType:@"plist"]] allKeysForObject:kStrUnavailable_IDLE] objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSLog(@"kStrAgentStateLunch = %@",kStrAgentStateLunch);

/* 2nd Part */

if([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"ja"]){
    NSLog(@"Agent language is Japan");
    kStrAgentStateLogin         =  @"ログイン";
    kStrAgentStateAvailable     =  @"利用可能";
    kStrAgentStateLunch         =  @"昼食";
    kStrAgentStateLogOff            = @"ログオフ";
    kStrUnavailable_IDLE            =  @"できない/アイドル";
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Agent language is English");
    kStrAgentStateLogin         =  @"Log In";
    kStrAgentStateAvailable     =  @"Available";
    kStrAgentStateLunch         =  @"Lunch";
    kStrAgentStateLogOff            = @"Log Off";
    kStrUnavailable_IDLE            =  @"Unavailable/IDLE";
}

}
```

Now the Values read in are same in both the cases. I checked them by doing NSLog also. So no problem in reading from the plist.

If I am using the 2nd part, result is as expected and extern is recognized everywhere. :)

If I am using the 1st part the problem is that I receive "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" :( wherever I am accessing these extern values and if I place my mouse over the variables in debugging mode I can see that it prints "out of scope" but Extern variables have scope throughout the entire code. Whats the mystery. Anyone???

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Cocoa's native localization stuff?

Comment: There are some reasons I feel for not using NSLocalizedString. 1)If I use NSLocalizedString, then I have to name the file Localizable.strings and feed all localised data there itself but I want to segregate things and put aux states data in a particular plist file so that its more organised. 2)I have mapping between Japanese and English strings... If I used Localizable.string it doesn't seem to map among the strings easily. In a simple plist it was pretty easy and straightforward to manage.

Comment: There's also a function that lets you use a different .strings file: `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`.

Comment: oh thanks I was unaware of that so problem 1) is solved but I have to map between Japanese and English strings some of the times in my code so I stored them as Key(Japanese) and Value(English) pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running under garbage collection, then the 1st part code needs to be retaining those strings. Otherwise they're liable to be deallocated shortly after you assign them, and you'll be left with pointers to deallocated objects. That's a great way to get EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes.

Comment: Oh Damn it how can I miss it. @Homer Thanks alot Sir.... Lot of regards to you and the answer was really quick. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although those `extern` variables do have the same lifetime as the program, that’s not necessarily true of the objects they point to:

```
kStrAgentStateLogin = @"ログイン";
```

The rvalue is a literal (or constant) `NSString`, which is never deallocated by the runtime so you don’t have to worry about memory management of that string.

```
kStrAgentStateLogin=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAuxStatesDictFile ofType:@"plist"]] allKeysForObject:kStrAgentStateLogin] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The rvalue is a string you do not own (i.e., you haven’t obtained it via a NARC method — new, alloc, retain, copy) so you cannot expect it to live throughout the execution of your program. You should use `-retain` to own that string, making it sure it will be valid throughout your program.